# Using non-sugared list syntax in the kind signature of a GADT with DataKinds

Tags: haskell, gadt, data-kinds

I was reading Giving Haskell a Promotion http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/ghp.pdf

And I came across this kind of syntax (which works if you use `{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}`):

```
data HList :: [*] -> * where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

Checking the information of the `[]` using `:info []`, tells me that the datatype of lists is:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

Which makes me think, that this style should also work, since the `[] a` type constructor is now lifted into a kind constructor:

```
data HList :: [] * -> * where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

But it doesn't, and gives me this error:

```
parse error on input `]'
```

Comment: Good point. Looks like a bug / not-fully-fleshed-out feature of DataKinds.

Comment: Probably, in order to implement this properly, you need more sorts than `BOX` (a sort is to a kind what a kind is to a type and GHC only has the sort `BOX`). You would need to treat `[]` as something like `BOX -> BOX`, but that doesn't exist at the moment. Another possibility would be "flattening" the type/kind hierarchy, as it typically done in a dependently typed language like Agda or Idris.

Comment: I've opened a GHC ticket for this as [10379](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10379).